# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib

Tags: swift2, xcode7, realm

Trying to revise an app created in Swift with Realm.

After updating to Xcode 7 and converting my Swift code to Swift 2.0, I get the following error when trying to run on iPhone simulator:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSecurity.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/michaelkaminowitz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D81B4C40-3614-44D6-91FC-BFAF2BA78BE2/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/90825092-A137-44EA-A253-76C43995E877/Welli.app/
```

Frameworks/RealmSwift.framework/RealmSwift
  Reason: image not found

I've already tried

1. Restarting Xcode and my Mac
2. Revoking and updating my development signing certificate
3. Adding Runpath Search Paths = $(inherited) @executable_path/Frameworks
4. Changing Embedded Content Contains Swift Code to 'Yes'

What other approaches do I need to take to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the appropriate version of Realm. It sounds like you're using a prebuilt `RealmSwift.framework` binary that was built with Xcode 6.

See https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#installation for always up-to-date installation instructions.

Answer (score 2):

I updated Realm to 2.0 and that fixed the problem. Thank you!